# Opening the app from show 2 app icons on React native/android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I just ejected from Expo and implemented a Deeplink the problem is when I open the link in android there are 2 apps that will open the first one is from an android manifest because I can change it a name but 2nd it I don't where it triggered or how it generated.